# Why are my Robust SE in a Negative Binomial smaller than non-robust SE?

Tags: standard-error, negative-binomial-distribution, robust, robust-standard-error

I am running a Negative Binomial Regression to predict a count variable of interest that is overdispersed and I've run into a problem. When I include robust standard errors by independent variable of interest is significant, and when I include non-robust standard errors the IV of interest is no longer significant. Does anyone know why this is the case and which specification is correct. Attached are two images of the results using the two error specifications

[image: Without Robust SE]

vs.

[image: With Robust SE]

Comment: It's hard to give general advice here without looking at the particular data. It's not unusual that such a situation occurs when the mean equation itself of the model does not fit well, e.g., due to omitted variables, nonlinearities, interactions, etc. So I would start by exploring this. But, of course, there might be other explanations as well.